# how to solve import error in my python code?

Tags: python

How to solve that problem i am facing in code import but i import but it not working.how to solve that problem

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import smtplib
import pyaudio
import platform
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import email
```

i face that problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-5-77331e0ff612>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/atiqpc/.spyder-py3/temp.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/atiqpc/.spyder-py3')
File "E:\anacoda\lib\site- 
packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py"line705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "E:\anacoda\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 
102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "C:/Users/atiqpc/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 9, in <module>
import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

Comment: It looks like that your python module `speech_recognition` is not installed. 
Check PYTHONPATH.

Comment: can you list out your folder structure? and how (and in which directory that) you run temp.py?

Comment: yes it is problem  runfile('C:/Users/atiqpc/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/atiqpc/.spyder-py3')

Comment: what files are in `.spyder-py3`? are you using `virtualenv`? have you installed libraries with `pip install -r requirements.txt`? if so, what's in `requirements.txt` python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [Read The Fine Manual](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/speech-recognition/) you'll see that
it is important to

```
$ pip install SpeechRecognition
```

along with dependencies.

Use this to help debug the situation:

```
import pprint
import sys

pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

Look for a directory corresponding to the place `pip` installed the package.
If you do

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/some/dir/containing/package
```

then `import` should be able to find it.